# DynamoDB PartiQL pagination using SDK

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, partiql

I'm currently working on pagination in DynamoDB using the JS AWS-SDK's executeStatement using PartiQL, but my returned object does not contain a NextToken (only the Items array), which is used to paginate.
This is what the code looks like (pretty simple):

```
const statement = `SELECT "user", "id" FROM "TABLE-X" WHERE "activity" = 'XXXX'`;
const params = {Statement: statement};
try {
    const posted = await dynamodb.executeStatement(params).promise();
    return { posted: posted };
} catch(err) {
    throw new Error(err);
}
```

I was wondering if anyone has dealt with pagination using PartiQL for DynamoDB.

Could this be because my partition key is a string type?

Still trying to figure it out.

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that if you want a NextToken DO NOT use version 2 of the AWS SDK for JavaScript. **Use version 3**. Version 3 will always return a NextToken, even if it is undefined.

From there you can figure out your limits, etc (default limit until you actually get a NextToken is 1MB). You'll need to look into the [dynamodb v3 execute statement method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/classes/executestatementcommand.html).

You can also look into [dynamodb paginators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/globals.html#paginatequery), which I've never used, but plan on studying.